# how to make a join to a joined table

Tags: mysql

i have a header table like this:

**items_header**

| item_id | created_by |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |

then I have a table where I store to who the item is assigned

**items_charge**

| item_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

so user with id 7 created an item and assigned it to the user with id 2.

Users are stored in a third table that is

**users**

| user_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | jack |
| 7 | frank |

I started joining items_header with items_charge to get both creator and assignee in one row:

```
SELECT item_id, created_by, user_id 
FROM items_header
    JOIN items_charge ON items_header.item_id=items_charge.item_id
```

so now I get:

| item_id | created_by | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 2 |

So far so good I want to add a join to users table to get the names instead of the ids so I tried to do:

```
SELECT item_id, creator.name, assignee.name 
FROM items_header
    JOIN items_charge ON items_header.item_id=items_charge.item_id
    JOIN users AS creator ON creator.user_id=items_header.created_by
    JOIN users AS assignee ON assignee.user_id=items_charge.user_id
```

but this obviously I get that items_charge.user_id is an unkown column because the third join doesn't include the items_header table but is between the other two tables only...

How can I get the following result?

| item_id | creator.name | assignee.name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | frank | jack |

Comment: may be, i'am wrong but your query seem to be fine , the problem may provide by the ambigu item_id in select statement.

Comment: A join can refer to any of the previously named tables, so putting a join between them doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: Change `SELECT item_id` to `SELECT items_header.item_id` and it should work fine.

Comment: @barmar no, the error I get is that items_charge.user_id column is unknown in ON clause (as I said in the question). I have no issues in the select part.

Comment: the duplicate question is not going to fix my issue at all. It is not the error I get

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. I just get "Column 'item_id' in field list is ambiguous". https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fteMRMumpQcqi2M6irMtR6/0

Comment: And I get the desired result when I correct the `SELECT` list. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kUS4KsicAWsuYr6ArfBVc2/1